# «Выше-40%-ный» — правильно ли?

Tags: орфография, лексика, дефис, сокращения, сложные-слова

Можно ли писать *вышесорокапроцентный* и *болеетрехэтажный*?
Если да, как сократить? И можно ли вообще?

*У этого теплового двигателя выше-40%-ный КПД*.

Или так?
*У этого теплового двигателя выше-40-процентный КПД*.
*Этот дом более-3-этажный*.

Comment: КПД - это он, потому что коэффициент. Более этажный дом - это как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вышесорокапроцентный? Болеетрёхэтажный?
Таких слов нет. Соответственно, нет и их сокращения.

С числительным сложные слова образуются путем "прибавления" к нему или существительного, или прилагательного (числ. + сущ.; числ. + прил.):
сорокалетний — 40-летний;
сорокакилометровый — 40-километровый (спец. — 40-км);
сорокапроцентный — 40%-й (спец. — 40%);
трёхэтажный — 3-этажный.

• У этого теплового двигателя КПД выше 40 %.
• В этом доме больше трёх этажей (лучше — не более, а больше, не 3 (цифрой), а трёх).

> В изданиях деловой и науч. лит. принята форма из числительного в цифровой форме, знака процентов, дефиса и падежного окончания *-ный, -ного, -ному* и т. д. Напр.: *10%-ный раствор*.
> Предпочтительной в таких изданиях следует считать форму с наращением одно- или двухбуквенного окончания по правилам наращения падежного окончания в порядковых числительных, обозначенных арабскими цифрами (см. 6.2.2). Напр.: *15%-й раствор, 20%-го раствора, 25%-му раствору* и т. д. Такая форма экономнее предыдущей и позволяет соблюсти единообразие в наращении падежных окончаний.
> В узкоспец. изданиях для высокоподготовленного читателя допустима форма без наращения падежного окончания, если контекст не может вызвать двояких толкований. Напр.: *В 5% растворе*.

[6.3. Числительные в составе сложных существительных и прилагательных](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html#id-6%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-623%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4)

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, нет. Такие формы в словарях не фиксируются. Почему бы просто не перефразировать?

*КПД этого теплового двигателя выше 40 процентов.*

*В этом доме более 3 этажей.*